# Multi-line dictionaries: Replace the key as per a word in value

Tags: python, regex, string, dictionary, replace

I have a dictionary in which I have to replace all the keys depending on a word in the value set. So my dictionary is:

```
  { 23: {'score': -8.639, 'char': False, 'word': 'positive'} }
  { 56: {'score': -5.6, 'char': False, 'word': 'neutral'} }
  { 89: {'score': -8.9, 'char': False, 'word': 'positive'} }
  { 34: {'score': -2.3, 'char': Tru, 'word': 'negative'} }
```

If the values part of dictionary i.e. the key word is positive then it should replace the key 23 with +1, for neutral's, the key 56 with 0 and for negative, the key 34 with -1.
The output will look like:

```
  { +1: {'score': -8.639, 'char': False, 'word': 'positive'} }
  { 0: {'score': -5.6, 'char': False, 'word': 'neutral'} }
  { +1: {'score': -8.9, 'char': False, 'word': 'positive'} }
  { -1: {'score': -2.3, 'char': Tru, 'word': 'negative'} }
```

Here is my code:

```
for n, line in enumerate(sys.stdin,1):
    d = ast.literal_eval(line)
    items = d.values()[0].items()
    if re.match("positive",d.get('sentimentoftweet')):
       n = str.replace(str(n),"+1")
    else:
       n = str.replace(str(n),"0")
```

Its not working and giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./linear.py", line 33, in <module>
for thing in d:
File "./linear.py", line 22, in gen_with_appropriate_name
if re.match("positive",d.get('sentimentoftweet')):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 137, in match
return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: `sentimentoftweet` is not there in your input data at all.

Comment: Is it required that you're passing the input via stdin? Wouldn't it be easier to store the data as an actual dictionary object and pass that to the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing incorrect key to `re.match`. For missing key `dict.get` returns `None`, use `d.get('word')`.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match('foo', None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-43-c75223170494>", line 1, in <module>
    re.match('foo', None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/re.py", line 156, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

You can match the strings or values using `==`:

```
if d.get('word') == 'positive':
   #do something
elif d.get('word') == 'negative'
   #do something else
```

**Code:**

```
import sys, ast
for line in sys.stdin:
    d = ast.literal_eval(line)
    key = list(d)[0]            #dictionary with just one key.
    if d[key]['word'] == 'positive':
        print {'+1': d[key]}
    elif d[key]['word'] == 'negative':
        print {'-1': d[key]}
    elif d[key]['word'] == 'neutral':
        print {'0': d[key]}
```

**Output:**

```
{'+1': {'char': False, 'score': -8.639, 'word': 'positive'}}
{'0': {'char': False, 'score': -5.6, 'word': 'neutral'}}
{'+1': {'char': False, 'score': -8.9, 'word': 'positive'}}
{'-1': {'char': True, 'score': -2.3, 'word': 'negative'}}
```

Comment: Most of this particular OP's questions show this kind of uncommon inputs. Do you really think it is okay to handle them like this?

Comment: @thefourtheye working on a research to analyze data so its not in my hands as the data is wierd

Comment: @kulkarni.ankita09 Why don't you format the data in such a way that, it will be easy to handle? So that you can program efficiently.

Comment: @thefourtheye good point but any data formatting tips? All I got is 1 text files with 10,000 lines & have to do analysis. The entire text file is like u see on top but even more fields.

Comment: @hcwhsa This works awesome. but, print {'-1': d[key]} how is it printing values?

Comment: @kulkarni.ankita09 `d[key]` returns the inner dict.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `d.get('word')` is not looking inside the nested dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

import pprint
import collections

dict_ = { 23: {'score': -8.639, 'char': False, 'word': 'positive'},
    56: {'score': -5.6, 'char': False, 'word': 'neutral'},
    89: {'score': -8.9, 'char': False, 'word': 'positive'},
    34: {'score': -2.3, 'char': True, 'word': 'negative'},
    }

new_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for key, value in dict_.items():
    if value['word'] == 'positive':
        key = '+1'
    elif value['word'] == 'neutral':
        key = '0'
    elif value['word'] == 'negative':
        key = '-1'
    else:
        raise ValueError('word not positive, neutral or negative')
    new_dict[key].append(value)

pprint.pprint(new_dict)
```